# Torque-4.2.9/Maui-3.3.1 Walltime per user group limit

Tags: scheduler, hpc, pbs, torque

I am trying to setup torque-4.2.9/maui-3.3.1 in such a way that a walltime limit is set on a user group basis. We are trying to implement a walltime of 5 days on a particular user group after which all jobs in that group should terminate. We have been searching for a solution in mailing lists since some time. Kindly suggest what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is functionality you can achieve with just Maui and Torque. I can say for certain that Torque doesn't have a way to do this. I think the best bet is to use an accounting manager (such as MAM or Gold) and see if there's a way to set that up to credit based on walltime.

Comment: Hi dbeer. We have successfully implemented the required querries of the customer. It was possible with torque with maui.